# Akka target nodes for remote routing

Tags: configuration, akka, remoting

I created a remote environment to deploy routees using the following:

[Routers with Remote Destinations](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting.html#routers-with-remote-destinations)

```
deployment {
  /router1 {
    router = round-robin-pool
    nr-of-instances = 7
    cluster {
      enabled = on
      allow-local-routees = off
      max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 3
      use-roles = ["backend"]
      target {
        nodes = ["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2560", "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2570"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. At the end any new node that joins will have routees deployed to it. I thought this configuration meant that "only" on target nodes the routees will be deployed but instead it deploys on "any" new node.

Is this how it works? How can I make the routees to be deployed only on specific nodes? Something must be wrong otherwise adding the "target" configuration does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting.html#routers-with-remote-destinations)

```
akka.actor.deployment {
    /parent/remotePool {
        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 10
        target.nodes = ["akka.tcp://app@10.0.0.2:2552", "akka.tcp://app@10.0.0.3:2552"]
    }
}
```

The above configuration, will clone the actor defined in the `Props` of the `remote pool` `10` times and deploy it evenly distributed across the two given target nodes.

Apply this configuration

```
deployment {
    /router1 {
        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 7
        target {
            nodes = ["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2560","akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2570"]
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that the `ClusterSystem` at `127.0.0.1:2560` and `ClusterSystem` at `127.0.0.1:2570` are running.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was only the location of the configuration. Also, it is not possible to use cluster aware routers with remote deployed routers, it won't build. But now there is another problem with remote deployed routers, nodes that are set on "target.nodes"  need to be up before starting the cluster whenever I use the "target.nodes". But if I comment out the "target.nodes", it will work no matter if I start the nodes before of after the seed node, this is really confusing and the docs say nothing about this.